# react-checkbox-tree checked state not updating using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using [react-checkbox-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-checkbox-tree) and trying to get it to work using hooks. I am calling useState for nodes, checked, and expanded:

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState<string[]>([]);
const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState<string[]>([]);
const [nodes, setNodes] = useState<Node[]>([]);
```

I pass the setChecked and setExpanded to the event handlers in checkbox tree:

```
        onExpand={(expanded) => {
                setExpanded(expanded);
                console.log(expanded);
            }
        }

        onCheck= {(checked) => {
            setChecked(checked);
            console.log(checked);
        }}
```

In my useEffect, I simulate a service call, and then call setNodes to set the nodes. This is working correctly - the checkbox tree is rendered. However, checking doesn't work. I added log statements and confirmed that checked array in onChecked is always empty. Expanding does seem to be working and it is correctly logging the expanded nodes, so not sure what I'm missing here.

Here is a simplified stripped down version of my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import 'react-checkbox-tree/lib/react-checkbox-tree.css';
import CheckboxTree, {Node} from 'react-checkbox-tree';

function CheckboxTreeTest() {

    const serviceResponseDummy = [{
        value: 'A',
        label: 'a',
        children: [
            { value: 'b', label: 'B', children: [] },
            { value: 'c', label: 'C', children: [{
                    value: 'd', label: 'D', children: []
                }]
            },
        ],
    }];

    const [checked, setChecked] = useState<string[]>([]);
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState<string[]>([]);
    const [nodes, setNodes] = useState<Node[]>([]);

    function dummyServiceCall():Promise<Node[]> {
        return new Promise<Node[]>((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(serviceResponseDummy);

            }, 1000);
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        dummyServiceCall()
        .then((response: Node[]) => {
            setNodes(response);
        });
    });

    return (
        <CheckboxTree
            nodes={nodes}
            checked={checked}
            expanded={expanded}
            onExpand={(expanded) => {
                    setExpanded(expanded);
                    console.log(expanded);
                }
            }

            onCheck= {(checked) => {
                setChecked(checked);
                console.log(checked);
            }}
        />
    );
}

export default CheckboxTreeTest;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect()` is running all the time, resulting in constant re-renders of the checkbox tree because `nodes` is constantly getting replaced. You can see this by putting a `console.log`s in the `.then()` block (as I have below).

To get the `useEffect()` to just run once, use an empty dependency array:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    dummyServiceCall().then((response: Node[]) => {
      console.log(`setting ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
      setNodes(response);
    });
  }, []);
```

I'm not familiar with react-checkbox-tree but when I ran your code in a codesandbox, it logged out sensible values for `checked` when I clicked on the *first* of the visible boxes (and correctly expanded and collapsed)